# angularjs-highlight text into paragraph

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular js. So, I want to highlight certain text from a HTML.

HTML CODE:

```
                    <div class="form-label logs-wrap" ng-repeat="x in res track by $index" ng-click="getBookingLog(x.bookingDBID)" ng-class="{selected: x.bookingDBID === bookingDBID}">

                      <span class="form-label">{{x.xml}}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

My CSS (Only selected class):

```
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

ANGULAR CODE:

```
$scope.bookingDBID = null;
    $scope.getBookingLog = function(bookingDBID){
      $scope.book = {};
      $scope.book.PID = $stateParams.id;
      $scope.book.bookingDBID = bookingDBID;

      $scope.showloader=true;
      var Indata ='data='+angular.toJson($scope.book)+'&method=getBookingLog&service=bookings';
      $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'sl/service/middleservice.php',
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
         data: Indata
         }).success(function (response) {
            // console.log(response);

            $scope.showloader=false;
            if(response == 'noSession')
            {
              location.href = 'login.php';
            }else
            {
              if(response)
              {
                $scope.res = response.reverse();              
                $scope.cnt = $scope.res.length;
              }
              $scope.loadingdiv= false;
              $scope.$modalInstance1 = $modal.open({
                  scope: $scope,
                  templateUrl: "bookinglog.html",
                  size: 'lg1',
              });
            }
       });

    }
```

I want to highlighted a **bookingDBID** in angular js but no any text highlighted.

[image]

i want to highlited in the image that 
**152422082503328306779**

**reservation_notif_id=bookingDBID**  result store

Any body having any idea please help to sort it out. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting response as `xml` ?

Comment: it's i create page on amazon bucket s3 service, yes i get response @ShashankVivek

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if this is what you needed

Comment: can u apply in my code ?? @ShashankVivek please

Comment: Check my updated plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/GcQI2nvtGMLUc2rWbTJB?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/GcQI2nvtGMLUc2rWbTJB?p=preview).

You can have

```
xmlTransform = function(data) {
    var x2js = new X2JS();
    var json = x2js.xml_str2json( data );
    return json.guitars.guitar;
};

$http.get('guitars.xml', {transformResponse:xmlTransform}).
            success(function(data, status) {
                 $scope.dataSet = data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status) {
                console.log("Request failed " + status);
            });
```

and in `html`

```
<div ng-controller="AppController" >
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="guitar in dataSet">
       <div class="selected"> {{guitar.model}} </div> <!-- HERE YOU HAVE HIGHLIGHTED -->
       <div>{{guitar.introyear}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```